# Dnspython- How to create a PTR dns crecord?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns, dnspython

Is there any way to create PTR record with python(dnspython)?
I want the record to locate in Reverse Lookup Zone in the appropriate X.Y.Z.in-addr.arpa zone.

I have tried the following but it did not work for me:

```
record = dns.update.Update('22.113.170.in-addr.arpa.')
record.add('26.22.113.170.in-addr.arpa.', 300, 'PTR', 'new-fqdn-please-work.com')
dns.query.tcp(record, DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS, timeout=5)
```

I also tried: `record.add('26.22.113.170',.....)`

I do not understand what am I doing wrong

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: Forgot to mention sorry- no I do not get any errors

Comment: The problem was on my side.
The security settings in Reverse Lookup Zone did not allowed updates from unsecure sources. Any ideas how can I "make" dnspython to a secure source who can perform dynamic updates on the reverse zone?
Thanks